# Can we have a FilledTorus region with any orientation in 3D?

Tags: graphics3d, regions

See [FilledTorus](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FilledTorus.html). It seems this new primitive/region must be symmetric about the xy-plane. I found this:
[image: new features]
at [list of changes](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn13.html), but I can't try it out because I will not upgrade for a while.

Answer (score 3):

Although `RegionQ @ FilledTorus[]` returns `True`, `TransformedRegion[FilledTorus[], transformation]` does not work (it returns `FilledTorus[]`).

**A work-around:** Use `DiscretizeRegion` to discretize `FilledTorus` object to get a `MeshRegion` object (`dr`) and apply the desired transformation to the `dr`:

```
ft = FilledTorus[{0, 0, 0}, {2/3, 1}];

trf = RotationTransform[Pi/3, {1, 1, 1}];

TransformedRegion[ft, trf]
```

[image]

```
dr = DiscretizeRegion[ft];

tdr = TransformedRegion[dr, trf];

Show[dr, tdr]
```

[image]

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], EdgeForm[], Red, tdr, Blue, dr}]
```

[image]

**Note:** `GeometricTransformation` works fine with `FilledTorus` as graphics primitive:

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], EdgeForm[], Red, GeometricTransformation[ft, trf], Blue, ft}]
```

[image]